# calculus volume integration question

Tags: calculus, volume, solid-of-revolution

I was wondering if anyone could help me with this volume integration problem:
Find the volume of region bounded by the curve $y=e^{x^2}$ and the lines $y=0, x=0$, and $x=1$ revolving around the $y$-axis.

When I did it I got $\pi$ as the answer.  Is this correct?

Comment: Can you also include *how* you did it?

Comment: Your answer does not look correct. if you explain your line of reasoning, we would be able to help and guide you more.

Comment: I found the integral from 1 to e of pi*(sqrt(lny))^2 dy.

Comment: I did this because when I drew it out it looked like e^x^2 was only defined from y=1 upward, and e^x^2 intersects with x=1 and the point y=e.  Since I am revolving around the y axis I thought the boundaries should be in terms of y and the radius in terms of x, so I solved for x using y=e^x^2 and  got x=sqrt(lny)

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, you are taking the curve $y=e^{x^2}$ from $x=0\text{ to }1$ and making a solid of revolution about the $y$-axis. This volume can be found with Pappus's ($2^{nd}$) Centroid Theorem, which states that the volume of a body of revolution is equal to the area times the length of the path of it centroid about the axis of revolution, let's say $V=2\pi RA$, where $R$ in this case is equal to

$$R=\frac{\int_0^1 x(e^1-y(x))dx}{\int_0^1 (e^1-y(x))dx}$$

Of course, the denominator is the area, hence we can say that

$$V=2\pi \int_0^1 x(e^1-y(x))dx=2\pi\int_0^1 x(e^1-e^{x^2})dx=\pi\int_0^1 (e^1-e^{t})dt$$

where $t=x^2$. Thus, we get the volume

$$V=\pi$$

This was verified by numerical integration. Your solution is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Washer Method:
$$\int_{0}^{e}\pi(1)^{2}dy-\int_{1}^{e}\pi(\sqrt{ln(y)})^{2}dy$$
Shell Method:
$$\int_{0}^{1}2\pi x e^{x^{2}}dx$$
And the result should be $$(e-1)\pi$$